# Scheduler process per tag folder

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler, airflow-2.x

I’m searching for some information about if is possible configure one scheduler processs of airflow per dag folder.
I'm using separated dag folders depending on the business subject, and I need to know if is possible configure one scheduler process per which one of these folders.
did someone knows if it is possible?

Comment: not aware of any such feature. why do you need such setup though? scheduler is pretty lightweight, so you need not have separate ones. can you share additional context.

Comment: @Pbd
My goal is achieve high availability.
In my context I have many flows to different business subjects.
I have sometimes to restart de scheduler to apply some configuration for example.
But I don't want to cause downtime in the scheduler that  prevents me from scheduling other tasks unrelated to the issue that caused the need to restart.
Do you understand my need?